# Anyone know the starting password for Auth Dialog Preview user?

Tags: facebook, open-graph-beta

I'm working on the Facebook Open Graph Beta and I am having a problem. Typical test users set up in code do not get assigned the "publish_actions" permission, no matter what you do.

So, I saw that under roles, FB added an "Auth Dialog Preview User" who automatically has the "publish_actions" permission enabled. the problem is that I do not know the password of this starting user. I usually set up test users in code, and grab the password from the API response.

Any ideas?

Comment: After more testing I found out that test users do get the publish_actions permission, but you need to define an aggregation first, then re-authenticate the test user. Still don't know the answer to the question, but don't need it now because I can use my other test users.